# Custom React `useFetch` hook - do I need to maintain multiple states?

Tags: reactjs, fetch, react-hooks

I've implemented a custom `useFetch` hook so do fetching around my app:

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

const useFetch = ({ url, defaultData = null }) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(defaultData)
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)
  const [error, setError] = useState(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(url)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(res => {
        setData(res)
        setLoading(false)
      })
      .catch(err => {
        setError(err)
        setLoading(false)
      })
  }, [])

  return [data, loading, error]
}

export default useFetch
```

Then it occurred to me... this will be used all over the app. How will it know which **data/loading/error** belongs to what call? When I make use of `useFetch` the first time, and then another use follows right behind it somewhere else in the app, does React track which internal state variables belong to which call of the hook?

Then I thought perhaps I need to do something more along the Redux lines and keep track of all the calls to the custom hook myself with the help of the `useReducer` hook:

```js
import { useEffect, useReducer } from 'react'

const reducer = (state, action) => {
  const { url, data, err } = action
  const currentState = state[url]

  switch (action.type) {
    case 'fetching':
      return { ...state, [url]: { ...currentState, loading: true } }
    case 'success':
      return { ...state, [url]: { ...currentState, loading: false, data } }
    case 'fail':
      return { ...state, [url]: { ...currentState, loading: false, err } }
    default:
      return state
  }
}

const useFetch = ({ url, defaultData = null }) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, {}, { type: 'fetching', url })
  const { data: d, loading: l, err: e } = state[url]

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(url)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => dispatch({ type: 'success', url, data }))
      .catch(err => dispatch({ type: 'fail', err }))
  }, [])

  return [d || defaultData, l, e]
}

export default useFetch
```

Do I need to manually keep track of all the calls to `useFetch` myself as in the 2nd example? Or does React handle this in its internals and the 1st example is all I need?

Comment: Custom hooks are for sharing _stateful logic_, not _state_. So something along the lines of your first snippet would work just fine.

Comment: @Tholle Good point. I guess it's hard breaking old habits!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each custom hook will have its own state and will not share state among different instances of the same hook. Hence you don't need to keep track of which state belongs to which hook.

Hooks will only share the logic and not data among different instances, much like `HOCs and Render Props`.

So the first example would work just right.

In your case multiple calls to `useFetch` will essentially lead to multiple calls to `useState` and [React FAQs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-does-react-associate-hook-calls-with-components) explain the independence of state with `useState` which does indeed answer your doubt

> React keeps track of the currently rendering component. Thanks to the
>   Rules of Hooks, we know that Hooks are only called from React
>   components (or custom Hooks — which are also only called from React
>   components).
>
> There is an internal list of “memory cells” associated with each
>   component. They’re just JavaScript objects where we can put some data.
>   When you call a Hook like useState(), it reads the current cell (or
>   initializes it during the first render), and then moves the pointer to
>   the next one. This is how multiple useState() calls each get
>   independent local state.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a pretty good example of what you can do for a more robust [`useFetch`](https://github.com/alex-cory/use-http) hook in my package [use-http](https://github.com/alex-cory/use-http)